# Processing self-referencing, complex data structure with Symfony Forms

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

How to process following data structure through Symfony Forms?

An entity which holds collection of an entity which has a relation to itself:

```
Order
    /** @var OrderProduct */
    $orderProducts

    public function getQuoteProducts()
    {
        return $this->quoteProducts;
    }

    public function addOrderProduct(OrderProduct $orderProduct)
    {
        if (!$this->orderProducts->contains($orderProduct)) {
            $this->orderProducts[] = $orderProduct;
            $orderProduct->setOrder($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOrderProduct(OrderProduct $orderProduct)
    {
        if ($this->orderProducts->contains($orderProduct)) {
            $this->orderProducts->removeElement($orderProduct);
        }

        return $this;
    }

OrderProduct
    /** @var Order */
    $order
    /** @var OrderProduct */
    $relatedOrderProducts

    public function addRelatedOrderProduct(OrderProduct $orderProduct)
    {
        if (!$this->relatedOrderProducts->contains($orderProduct)) {
            $this->relatedOrderProducts[] = $orderProduct;
            $orderProduct->setMainOrderProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRelatedOrderProduct(OrderProduct $orderProduct)
    {
        if ($this->relatedOrderProducts->contains($orderProduct)) {
            $this->relatedOrderProducts->removeElement($orderProduct);
            $orderProduct->setMainOrderProduct(null);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

The request:

```
'order' => [
    'some_order_property' => 'value',
    // ...
    'orderProducts' => [
        'some_order_product_property' => 'value',
        // ...
        'relatedOrderProducts' => [
            [
                'some_order_product_property' => 'value',
                // ...
            ],
            [
                'some_order_product_property' => 'value',
                // ...
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
```

Forms:

```
OrderType

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('orderProducts', OrderProductCollectionType::class)
            ->add(...);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => Order::class]);
    }

OrderProductCollectionType

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'type'         => OrderProductType::NAME,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'prototype'    => true,
        ]);
    }

OrderProductType

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('relatedOrderProducts', RelatedOrderProductCollectionType::class)
            ->add(...);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => OrderProduct::class]);
    }

RelatedOrderProductCollectionType

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'type'         => RelatedOrderProductType::NAME,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'prototype'    => true,
        ]);
    }

RelatedOrderProductType

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(...);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => OrderProduct::class]);
    }
```

This setup works, only it doesn't relate `OrderProducts` from `RelatedOrderProductType` form to the `Order` (so they have `order_id` set to `null`).
When this relation is forced (eg. with a `FormEvent` listener), then all the relations are getting deleted on subsequent form submission. That's most likely due to `orphanRemoval=true` set on the entity.

Probably some details are missing from my example, but me general question is: can this data structure be processed with Symfony Forms? If so, then how?

Comment: We need to see entity code. Moreover if you're trying to re-relate products related to other product but the one you're showing in the form, you'll obtain a delet due to `orphanRemoval` as you highligthed correclty in your question.

Comment: @DonCallisto I added collection's add and remove methods. Do you need anything else?